# Mybatis generator generates POJO class with Long instead of Custom Object

Tags: java, mybatis, pojo, spring-mybatis, mybatis-generator

In mybatis generator plugin if we generate POJO classes and XML mappers file, the POJO class looks like this,

```
public class User {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Long team;                 //<-------------Team is a Long field
    Long accounts;             //<-------------accounts is also a long field

    //getters and setters
}
```

Normally when a POJO class looks like this,

```
public class User {
    Long id;
    String name;
    Team team;                   //<----------Team object
    List<Account> accounts;      //<----------List of accounts

    //getters and setters
}
```

I can use the following getter method of the model class field to select the User object and its corresponding properties,

```
  User user = user.getUser(user);
  //get user object properties like
  user.getTeam(); //<------will get the Team object for the user object
```

But currently using the MBG(MyBatis Generator) it only works for XML mappings and with the generated POJO classes I will only be able to get the team id primary key id field.

So how can I set MBG to generate model classes with the corresponding object based on the foreign column or how to fetch the team Object with the POJO class generated by the MBG?

Comment: Which process are you using for generate the xml files?